# Show form based on drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry, if this has already been asked but I can't find a solution. I'm currently have a drop down list and depending on what option value in the drop down list is selected, a different form will show up. So if I had for example 10 values in the drop down list box, each value would show a different form if selected.

```
<select id="state" name="state">
        <option value="nsw">New South Wales</option>
        <option value="qld">Queensland</option>
        <option value="vic">Victoria</option>
        <option value="nt">Northern Territory</option>
        <option value="tas">Tasmania</option>
        <option value="sa">South Australia</option>
        <option value="wa">Western Australia</option>
        <option value="act">Australian Capital Territory</option>
        <option value="notinoz">Not in Australia</option>
</select>

<form id="testform">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Example multiple select</label>
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>

<form id="testform2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
          <option>5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Example multiple select</label>
        <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
          <option>5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
    </form>
```

These are test javascript functions that are not working.

```
$("#nsw").on(function () {
    $("#testform").toggle();
});

$("#qld").on(function () {
        $("#testform2").toggle();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery code is incorrect.  You use `.on` but not specifying which event.. basically like saying "on.. what?".  Furthermore, you don't need to use `.on` for a change event.. you can just use `.change`.

I think the cleanest way of handling this would be a `switch` statement.

```
$("#state").change(function(){
    stateChange($(this).val());
});

function stateChange(stateValue){
    $("form").hide();

    switch(stateValue){
     case 'nsw':
        $("#testform").show();
      ;
     case 'qld':
        $("#testform2").show();
      ;
     // so on and so on...
  }
}
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dktqv837/5/) for you to use.  It's basically all of your code.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted so that this question can be seen as answered.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your Jquery code is wrong, Check my solution. 
I got selected value from dropdown (on change event) and showed relevant form according to selected value of dropdown
check below example and make necessary changes..

```js
$("#state").change(function() {
  let state = this.value; //get state

  $('.state-form').hide(); //hide all forms

  $("#form-" + state).show(); //show only related form
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="state" name="state">
  <option value="">--- Please Select ---</option>
  <option value="nsw">New South Wales</option>
  <option value="qld">Queensland</option>
</select>

<form id="form-nsw" class="state-form" style="display:none;">
  <hr> new south wales form
  <hr>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Example multiple select</label>
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>

<form id="form-qld" class="state-form" style="display:none;">
  <hr> Queensland form
  <hr>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Example multiple select</label>
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I wouldn't say ***there are lots of issues in there***... the only thing incorrect was their implementation of jQuery.  Even though you're answer is correct, you made it more difficult for the OP with the new form ids and unnecessary javascript... since their HTML was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Because your jquery code is wrong. you have to do something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#state").on('change',function() {
    $("form").hide();
    if($(this).val()=="nsw")
      $("#testform").show();
    else if($(this).val()=="qld")
      $("#testform2").show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is also a question similar form the question above. what if the items in the dropdown menu are from the database?

```
<div class="col-5 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 ">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-2 col-xl-11 form-group p-1">
                     <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1"  class="form-label "><b>Request Type</b></label>
                     <select class="form-control @error('xcmtype') is-invalid @endif" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="xcmtype">
                     <option disabled selected>--Select--</option>
                     @if($cmtype)
                     @foreach($cmtype as $type)
                     <option value='{{$type->type_name}}' @if(old('xcmtype') == $type->ty_name) selected @endif> {{$type->ty_name}}</option>
                     @endforeach
                     @endif
                  </select>
                  @error('cmtype') 
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">Department is required</div>
                  @endif
                </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
```